# Batch Process Files in Folder to Python Script Arguments

Tags: python, linux, bash, batch-processing

I'm trying to use this Python script to batch process filenames in place of the arguments.

The script runs as follows:

```
$ python /root/vrn/raw2obj.py --volume /root/vrn/output/file-name1105.raw \
   --image /root/vrn/JPEGS/scaled/file-name1105.jpg \
   --obj /root/workfolder/output/file-name1105.obj`
```

The source of the script can be found here [vrn/raw2obj.py](https://github.com/AaronJackson/vrn/blob/master/raw2obj.py).

I tried to inherit a similar structure used for batch FFmpeg processes without any luck. The filenames are all the same between `--volume` `--image` and `--obj`, it's only the extensions that vary.

The files are numbered as well if it is easier that way to have a reg expression, it goes from `file-name0000 to file-name2254` in a sequence of 1.

Is it possible to do a search or `for i in` the `/root/vrn/JPEGS/scaled/` folder (using linux bash only) and use the filename without extension for the arguments above using Bash?

Comment: You should put your code into functions. Check out `os.walk` and `glob.glob` for ways of recursively finding files. `glob` might be faster and easier for you. Also, `os.path` can manipulate filenames for you removing/adding extensions, etc.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I should've mentioned in the post above that I'm not very familiar with python so I wouldn't be able to implement it on my own. I was hoping for some bash solution to be possible since I'm more familar with that

Answer (score 0):

`for i in file-name{0000..2254}; do python /root/vrn/raw2obj.py --volume /root/vrn/output/"$i".raw --image /root/vrn/JPEGS/scaled/"$i".jpg --obj /root/workfolder/output/"$i".obj 
 done` Worked for me. It ran through the filenames sequentially and runs the script on all of the one by one.